Partition not mounting - showing as smaller size than it is
I am creating a binary image from various Android partitions using dd. I then mount the image using losetup and mount. Most of the partitions mount correctly except the last one (userdata).
# sudo fdisk -l user.bin
Disk user.bin: 14.68 GiB, 15758000128 bytes, 30777344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 03B183AF-9DB5-4EFC-805E-9097AE08BEF0

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
user.bin1     55552    57599     2048    1M Linux filesystem
user.bin2     57600    59647     2048    1M Linux filesystem
user.bin3     59648    61695     2048    1M Linux filesystem
user.bin4     61696    63743     2048    1M Linux filesystem
user.bin5     63744    64255      512  256K Linux filesystem
user.bin6     64256   129791    65536   32M Linux filesystem
user.bin7    129792   195327    65536   32M Linux filesystem
user.bin8    195328  4389631  4194304    2G Linux filesystem
user.bin9   4389632  8583935  4194304    2G Linux filesystem
user.bin10  8583936 10681087  2097152    1G Linux filesystem
user.bin11 10681088 12778239  2097152    1G Linux filesystem
user.bin12 12778240 12827391    49152   24M Linux filesystem
user.bin13 12827392 12958463   131072   64M Linux filesystem
user.bin14 12958464 12978943    20480   10M Linux filesystem
user.bin15 12978944 12999423    20480   10M Linux filesystem
user.bin16 12999424 13097727    98304   48M Linux filesystem
user.bin17 13097728 13163263    65536   32M Linux filesystem
user.bin18 13163264 13327103   163840   80M Linux filesystem
user.bin19 13327104 13329151     2048    1M Linux filesystem
user.bin20 13329152 13331199     2048    1M Linux filesystem
user.bin21 13331200 13339391     8192    4M Linux filesystem
user.bin22 13339392 13341439     2048    1M Linux filesystem
user.bin23 13341440 13472511   131072   64M Linux filesystem
user.bin24 13472512 30777310 17304799  8.3G Linux filesystem

Above shows a 8.3GB partition. Then I use sudo losetup -vP -f user.bin and then I check again:
# sudo fdisk -l /dev/loop28p24
Disk /dev/loop28p24: 2.88 GiB, 3089117184 bytes, 6033432 sectors

The size is reduced!! And, when I try to mount it I get an error and dmesg shows:
[28136.901092] loop29: detected capacity change from 0 to 6033432
[28136.921405] EXT4-fs (loop29): bad geometry: block count 1572864 exceeds size of device (754179 blocks)

Why would losetup load this as a smaller partition than it is?
Edit: included extra info above per comment and some info below:
ls -l user.bin 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15758000128 Nov  5 21:45 user.bin


"(omitted other lines)" – Maybe you shouldn't have omitted them. Maybe fdisk -l clearly told you that user.bin has about 19505943 sectors. This would place the formal end of the last partition (sector number 30777310) far beyond the end of the file. What is the output of ls -l user.bin? If I'm right then the questions are: Why the discrepancy between the size of the image and the 24th entry in its partition table? Is the image too small?

What was the original "logical sector size" of the device you imaged this from?

OK, now I see that the hypothesis from my first comment is false. The size of the file seems just right. The problem with /dev/loop28p24 is surprising indeed.
